# пытаюсь сделать деплой своего react приложения на https://render.com/

Tags: reactjs, axios, развертывание, package

Пытаюсь сделать деплой своего react приложения на https://render.com/
я не знаю как я должен **установить сервер**.
Локально все просто он запускается одновременно с фронтендом и все работает
В приложении есть запроссы по эндпоинтам и они не работают. (тк не работает сервер)

`const response = await axios.post(/api/v1/login, { username: name, password });`

`const response = await axios.post(/api/v1/sugnip, { username: name, password });`

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)